# I need help converting Intel inline asm to AT&T so I can compile it with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

This is the original code:

```
#define CPU_PREFETCH(cache_line)            \
{ int* address = (int*) (cache_line);       \
    _asm mov edx, address                   \
    _asm prefetcht0[edx]                    \
}

#define CPU_GET_CYCLES(low)                 \
{                                           \
    _asm    rdtsc                           \
    _asm    mov dword ptr [low], eax        \
}

#define CPU_SYNC                            \
{                                           \
    _asm    mov eax, 0                      \
    _asm    cpuid                           \
}

#define CPU_CACHE_FLUSH(cache_line)         \
{ int* address = (int*) (cache_line);       \
    _asm mov edx, address                   \
    _asm clflush[edx]                       \
    _asm mfence                             \
}
```

Thanks to Jester, I now have this:

```
#define CPU_PREFETCH(cache_line) \
{ \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("prefetcht0 %0" : : "m" (*(int*)cache_line)); \
}

#define CPU_GET_CYCLES(low) \
{ \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (low) : : "%edx"); \
}

#define CPU_SYNC \
{ \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid" : : : "%eax", "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx"); \
}

#define CPU_CACHE_FLUSH(cache_line) \
{ \
    __asm__ ("clflush %0; mfence" : : "m" (*(int*)cache_line)); \
}
```

Evidently, gcc doesn't like **volatile** with clflush.
Thanks everyone.

I am trying to compile [Slicing-By-8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/slicing-by-8/) with gcc as a dll so I can use it in my VB6 app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would be nice to use proper inline functions. Anyway, here is your macro version:

```
#define CPU_PREFETCH(cache_line) \
{ \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("prefetcht0 %0" : : "m" (*(int*)cache_line)); \
}

#define CPU_GET_CYCLES(low) \
{ \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a" (low) : : "%edx"); \
}

#define CPU_SYNC \
{ \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("cpuid" : : : "%eax", "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx"); \
}

#define CPU_CACHE_FLUSH(cache_line) \
{ \
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("clflush %0; mfence" : : "m" (*(int*)cache_line)); \
}
```

Comment: Man, that looks beautiful and looks as though you know exactly what you're doing :)   Anyway, I get this error now: Error: operand size mismatch for `clflush'

Comment: I tried to click that this post was useful but I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 3):

Instead of converting your Intel syntax to AT&T, why don't you tell GCC that you just want to compile Intel syntax?

You can do it like this:

add this line before any other assembly lines:

```
asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n");
```

Then run GCC like this:

`gcc -o my_output_file -masm=intel my_src_file.c`

Thanks to [stingduk](http://www.reversing.be/users.php?mode=profile&uid=21) at [BiW Reversing](http://www.reversing.be/article.php?story=20051203194931893).

Comment: He forgot to add the backslash.

Comment: Even with this, the `_asm bare assembly line` construct will not work with GCC.